# How can I make a toolbar stay on the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I have a screen with some TextViews and EditTexts, and a toolbar.
When I click on an edit text to input some text, the toolbar disappears
How can I make the toolbar be on the screen all the time, even when I introduce the text(or when I scroll, if I introduce a scroll view)

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/createTreasureScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".view.fragment.CreateTreasureFragment">

        <Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarTreasureHeight"
                android:background="@color/Blue"
                android:elevation="@dimen/loginToolbarElevation"
                android:title="@string/page_title"
                android:titleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbarMarginStart"
                android:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarStyle"
                android:titleTextColor="@color/White"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/parent"
                app:titleEnabled="false" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Put your toolbar in activty and a container layout below, and add you TextViews and Edittext in Fragments

Comment: please send complete xml file code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FrameLayout`. This will allow you to keep your `Toolbar` always on top of the other views, and being visible if you add a `ScrollView`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/createTreasureScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".view.fragment.CreateTreasureFragment">

    <!--Add your other views here-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarTreasureHeight"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:elevation="@dimen/loginToolbarElevation"
        android:title="@string/page_title"
        android:titleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbarMarginStart"
        android:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbarStyle"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:titleEnabled="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```